# Regex helping. Can't solve this by myself

Tags: regex, pcre

I need help with regex.
This is text, what I have:

```
#1234 10% commet@timing:information and other activity2@timing
#12d34 10% commet@timing:information and other activity2@timing
#3132 10% testing@1.10:test commit  frontend@44min:other comments  
#3132 10% testing@1.10:test commit 2
```

So, I need to get every **text@text:text with spaces** and **text@text with spaces** entries.
That is what I have now: https://regex101.com/r/zgILCE/1 
My regex `/(\w*)\@([\w.]*)\:((\w|\s)*) /` doesn't work well.

UPD.
I need regex match this:
one@one:some text
one@one
one@one:one

Legend:

one - one word (maybe with numbers)

some text - regular text (maybe with numbers)

Comment: Is every line a separate string?

Comment: You need to match the spaces as well, or just text around a `@`?

Comment: Is it what you are looking for: https://regex101.com/r/I2c53h/1 ?

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte nearly. I need it to much this too: activity2@timing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for:

```
(?<!\S)(\w+)@([\w.]*:)?(\w+(?:\h\w+)*)(?!\S)
```

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/I2c53h/2)

details:

```
(?<!\S) # not preceded by a character that isn't a whitespace
(\w+)
@
([\w.]*:)? # according to your requirements this part is optional
(
    \w+ (?:\h\w+)* # way to include eventual single spaces between words
)
(?!\S) # not followed by a character that isn't a whitespace
```

Comment: I'm sorry, how can we exclude this situation: "testing@test text" from regex? Thank you in advance

Comment: So, it must get only entries with ":" Like:

"testing@1.10:test text" and "testing@1.10:word"

Answer (score 2):

I would use the following RegEx:

```
\s+\S+\@\S+(\s+|$)
```

The above RegEx matches white spaces, then any non-space characters followed by an @ sign, then any non-space characters, followed by spaces. This makes it match through the : through the next space.

The $ at the end will make it still match if the last item in the file doesn't have a line-ending at the end of the file. Otherwise, with a global match modifier the \s is going to match a vertical white-space anyway (aka a line ending)

If per comments you really only want to match a single white space and not however many are in the document:

```
\s\S+\@\S+(\s|$)
```

Comment: I updated my answer to get rid of the negative class match [^\s] since \S is the equivalent of that.

BTW, this is my favorite RegEx Helper:
https://regexr.com/

Comment: Sorry, i have a mistake in my post. Now I've edited it. regex must match not only one word after :
It must match this: text@text:text with spaces
This:  text@text:text
And this:  text@text

Thank you

Comment: I updated my answer. That's pretty quick / simple to fix for.

Comment: [`(?<=\s)\S+\@\S+(?=\s|$)`](https://regex101.com/r/zgILCE/3) gets rid of additional whitespaces and also checks against the end of the line instead of just whitespaces (your current regex excludes the last line if there is no text following the `x@x` part of the string)

Comment: That link shows it matching all the entries. If you're now saying you only want it to match one white space and not two white-space in a row, that can easily be done but wasn't what was described. 

My big question to you is, if you want a standard white-space added to whatever you extract, why don't you just add the white-space back manually after pulling out the RegEx? Why do you need the exact white space from the file, yet limiting it to only one space? That doesn't make any sense.

Comment: BTW, typically \s with a global modifier will match a line-ending as a vertical white space. As a result I'm pretty sure its going to do what you're asking it to do.

Comment: Solution is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47536453/5670509, but thank you for your answers. Maybe I put the wrong task.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$string1='#3132 10% testing@1.10:test commit  frontend@44min:other comments ';


$string=explode(' ',$string1);

echo '<pre>';

$myArray=array();
foreach ($string as $row){
    if (strpos($row, '@') !== false) {
        $myArray[]=$row;
    }
}

print_r($myArray);
```

I will provide a more php solution not so much of a regex. I am exploding your string to get an array and the i search the array fields with a loop to find `@`. After i do that i just return the field.

The output is :

```
Array
(
    [0] => testing@1.10:test
    [1] => frontend@44min:other
)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But I need exactly regex, not php code.

Comment: Your tag was php also that's why i provided php. Anyway you found your solution. Cheers!!!